# Two background tasks in a row and loading gif (in)visibility

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, background-process

I've been banging my head on my desk for a while with this problem.

**So, the setup:**
I have a Form doing "heavy" operations (data loading, etc...). I have a thread created on the fly to perform these (in, let's say, a "doWorkInBackground" method), and my form displays a small animated gif meanwhile. To detail that, at the start of the method, the gif is made visible, and invisible at the end, both being done asynchronously (to be thread safe).
The problem being that at a certain point of my program, I have two calls to doWorkInBackground in a row, and the second one seems to be called before the gif is made invisible by the first... therefore, the gif remains invisible for the duration of the second call.

**-General methods**

```cs
// Perform a thread-safe modification on a control
protected void addControlWork(Control c, Action a)
{
    if (c.InvokeRequired)
        c.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(a));
    else
        a();
}

// Perform a background task, displaying the loading gif and disabling other controls
protected void doWorkInBackground(MethodInvoker )
{
    addControlWork(loadingPicture, delegate() { loadingPicture.Visible = true; });
    addControlWork(mainPanel, delegate() { mainPanel.Enabled = false; });
    f.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(endWorkInBackground), null);
}

// At the end of the background task, hides the loading gid, enables the other controls
protected void endWorkInBackground(IAsyncResult result)
{
    if (this.Disposing)
        return;
    addControlWork(loadingPicture, delegate() { loadingPicture.Visible = false; });
    addControlWork(mainPanel, delegate() { mainPanel.Enabled = true; });
}
```

**-Usage:**

```cs
private void aListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doWorkInBackground((MethodInvoker)(() =>
    {
        object[] source = HeavyOperation();;
        addControlWork(aComboBox, delegate()
        {
            // Changing DataSource fires aComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
            // including a second call to doWorkInBackground
            aComboBox.DataSource = source;
        });
    }));
}

private void aComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object s, EventArgs e)
{

    doWorkInBackground((MethodInvoker)(() =>
    {
        // uninteresting stuff
        object[] range = aHeavyLoading();
        object[] source = anotherHeavyLoading();
        addControlWork(uneListBox, delegate() { aListBox.Items.AddRange(range); });
        addControlWork(uneComboBox, delegate() { aComboBox.DataSource = source; });
}));

}
```

In the exemple above, we can see that when aListBox_SelectedIndexChanged is called, aComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged is called right after. There is the problem, my gif remains invisible.

I don't have access to await/async. If you have a solution, that'd be appreciated, thanks.

*Note: I just put this problem here for the sake of curiosity. I "solved" this problem by preventing the firing of aComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged in aListBox_SelectedIndexChanged.*

Comment: You say you can't use async/await; can you use .NET 4.0? If so, Task continuations look like a solution

Comment: That would have been easy :p No, I can't use 4.0. I'm searching for a "hard" solution.